# What are the pros/cons of Windows SDK 7.1 over 7.0 for VS2008/C++?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, winapi

I use Visual Studio 2008 and work pretty exclusively with plain old C++. At present I'm using the Windows SDK 7.0, but I see that the VS2010 compilers are available with 7.1. I don't use C# or .NET, or even MFC or ATL, but I do use STL extensively.

If I switch my VS2008 to use 7.1, will I need to distribute VS2010 runtimes instead? Are there any other practical benefits or detriments to upgrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will I need to distribute VS2010 runtimes instead
>   No, Windows SDK does not upgrade your VC runtime. Only SDK headers, libs and tools are updated.
>
> Are there any other practical benefits or detriments to upgrading?
>   You need to compare what features in the SDK you are using in your project and check [what is new](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717428.aspx) and see where they overlaps. Most of the change are probably of no use to you so it does not make sense to list them all.